# Multiple Galleries with Magnific Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm trying to create a page with a few galleries using the Magnific-Popup jQuery plug-in. I different sections contained in `div`s with separate ids and a `.gallery` class containing the images.

```
<div id="content_1">
    <p>Some content</p>
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="img/pic_1"><img src="img/pic_1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="img/pic_2"><img src="img/pic_2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content_2">
    <p>More content</p>
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="img/pic_3"><img src="img/pic_3.jpg"></a>
        <a href="img/pic_4"><img src="img/pic_4.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get the galleries to be separate in the popup I initialized the script multiple times for each content section. When I do this, however, after the first content section, there are more images in the gallery popup (twice as much to be exact) than I linked to. I'm new to javascript, so I'm not sure if I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603714/magnific-popup-limit-items-to-direct-siblings

Answer (score 18):

From the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#gallery):

> To have multiple galleries on a page, you need to create a new
>   instance of Magnific Popup for each seperate gallery. For example
>
> ```
> <div class="gallery">
>     <a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 1 (gallery #1)</a>
>     <a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 2 (gallery #1)</a>
> </div>
> <div class="gallery">
>     <a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 1 (gallery #2)</a>
>     <a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 2 (gallery #2)</a>
>     <a href="http://vimeo.com/123123" class="mfp-iframe">Open video (gallery #2). Class mfp-iframe forces "iframe" content type on this item.</a> 
> </div>
> ```

Javascript

> ```
> $('.gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
>     $(this).magnificPopup({
>         delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
>         type: 'image',
>         gallery: {
>           enabled:true
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I took this same approach (because of the documentation), but it shares all the images from each gallery WITH each gallery until I reload the page (using turbolinks, maybe that's part of the issue?)