# Javascript location for multple galleries in magnificPopup

Tags: javascript, html

Little bit new here but I searched around for this specifically and couldn't find an answer.

I'm currently trying to get multiple galleries on a single page with the magnificPopUp plugin, and I know this has been discussed ([Multiple Galleries with Magnific Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654120/multiple-galleries-with-magnific-popup))

```
$('.gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
$(this).magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled:true
    }
});
});
```

This might seem like a dumb question, but where do I place that JavaScript code? in the magnific-popup.js file? Or do I make a new one and call it? I'm relatively new with JS and I'm working on it, but I've tried placing it in different locations and get a JavaScript error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can put in the same page between `<script></script>` tag before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm getting an error " $ is not a function " when I try that also. It's a similar message to what I was getting when I had it in other places inside the js file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Call them from the same page where you have your galleries. Make sure to include jQuery and MagnificPopup.js **BEFORE** the Magnific Popup initialization script. See sequence below.

They can be put in the `<head></head>` of your HTML or just before the ending `</body>` tag. As long as they follow the sequence. Also include `$(document).ready()` around your script.

```
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<!-- Popup initialization code should be executed after document ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
  $(this).magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled:true
    }
  });
 });
});
</script>
```